# ios17 safari AudioContext (Web Audio API) problem

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api, audiocontext, ios17

Since I upgraded to ios17 my AudioContext is not working on Safari.

I have a simple  element that I connect a gain node through AudioContext.  The audio loads the .mp3 file (remaining time is updated correctly).  But when I press play, nothing happens.  No error in the console

```js
 audioCtx = new AudioContext();
const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 2;
const sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you ran into this bug (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261414). It got marked as fixed but seems not to be shipped yet.